# Does Feature Normalization affect Gradient Descent | Linear Regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, machine-learning-model, gradient-descent, feature-scaling

am new to datascience and i want to learn linear regression so i coded linear regression from scratch and performed gradient descent to find the best $w_\theta$ and $b_\theta$ values using a tutorial. And it went just fine i was able to find the best $w_\theta$ , $b_\theta$ values and i ploted the *line-of-best-fit* (below).

[image: Before Standization]

And the *gradient descent* code i used to find the $w_\theta$ , $b_\theta$ values is below .

```py
def step_gradient_descent(data,m,b,learning_rate=0.0001):
        b_gradient= m_gradient = 0
        N=float(len(data))
        for i in range(len(data)):
                [x,y]=data[i]
                y_=(m*x)+b
                m_gradient+= - (2/N)*(x*(y-y_))
                b_gradient+= -(2/N)*(y-y_)
        #print("m ={}, b ={}".format(m_gradient,b_gradient))
        m_new = m-(learning_rate*m_gradient)
        b_new = b-(learning_rate*b_gradient)
        return (m_new,b_new)

def perform_gradient_descent(data,m,b,lr=0.0001,epochs=1000):
        m_array=b_array=[]
        for i in range(epochs):
                if(i % 100 == 0 ):
                        print("Running {}/{}".format(i,epochs))
                (m,b) = step_gradient_descent(data,m,b,lr)
        return (m,b,m_array,b_array)
```

and then i performed features normalization / standization on $x$ , $y$ below

```py
def featureNormalize(data):
    mean = np.mean(data , axis=0 )
    std = np.std(data , axis=0 )
    norm = ( data - mean ) / std
    return norm
```

and then after that i plotted the *line-of-best-fit* , which was different from the above plotted one.
[image: after feature normalization]

So things i tried to get back the previous *line-of-best-fit* as before are

- changing learning rate ( $r$ )
- changing epochs ( $n$ )

which didnot work out. So my understanding is that feature normalization / standization should not have any effect on the gradient descent but that didnot happen in this case. Just curious to figure out what's happening in my case.

Link to my [notebook](https://github.com/guruprasaad123/ml_for_life/blob/master/from_scratch/gradient-descent/batch-gradient-descent.ipynb)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard normalization let gradient descent **converge faster**. That's why most cases normalization is applied (of course it also eliminate effect of different scale features values).

In this [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-mean-normalization-help-in-gradient-descent) topic it is explained well.

Your learning rate is very small. I think there is not enough number of iterations to coverge local minimum. This graph explains well the effect of learning rate to gradient descent:

[image]

You may want to check my [another](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56285/lowering-learning-rate-makes-my-accuracy-on-the-validation-set-go-down) answer for it.

Comment: makes sense let me try it

Comment: Hope it works! Please share the results :)

Comment: sure will so :-)

Comment: I have found the answer: I just had to perform L2 Normalization with gradient-descent. please find the link to my [notebook](https://github.com/guruprasaad123/ml_for_life/blob/master/from_scratch/gradient-descent/batch-gradient-descent.ipynb) @llker Kurtulus

Comment: @guru_007 One fun exercise is to create either a series of plots like your original for different epochs - or for a nice challenge append them into an animated image. You'll see the best fit line evolve over time. Also in general you should at least check that the mean of the residuals is zero - if not the algorithm hasn't converged.

Comment: sure @DavidWaterworth I'll try that one ! cheers

Comment: @IlkerKurtulus i have shared my results please do check my [notebook](https://github.com/guruprasaad123/ml_for_life/blob/master/from_scratch/gradient-descent/batch-gradient-descent.ipynb)

Comment: Sorry! Somehow I missed the notification. That's a great work and solution!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to perform L2 Normalization , it worked like charm .

#### Theoritical Explanation :

$$
\begin{align}
w_\theta &= - \frac{2}{N} \left( x * \left(y - \left(m*x+b\right) \right) \right) +  \frac{\lambda}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^2   \\
b_\theta &= - \frac{2}{N} \left(y - \left(m*x+b\right) \right) + \frac{\lambda}{2m} \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i^2  \\
\end{align}
$$

#### Change in code :

```py
def step_gradient_descent_reg(data,m,b,learning_rate=0.0001,_lambda=1):
        b_gradient= m_gradient = 0
        N=float(len(data))
        for i in range(len(data)):
                [x,y]=data[i]
                y_=(m*x)+b
                m_gradient+= - ( (2/N)*(x*(y-y_)) ) + ( (_lambda / 2 * m ) * (np.sum(np.square(m_gradient))) )
                b_gradient+= - (2/N)*(y-y_)  + ( (_lambda / 2 * m ) * (np.sum(np.square(m_gradient))) )
        #print("m ={}, b ={}".format(m_gradient,b_gradient))
        m_new = m-(learning_rate*m_gradient)
        b_new = b-(learning_rate*b_gradient)
        return (m_new,b_new)

def perform_gradient_descent_reg(data,m,b,lr=0.0001,epochs=1000):
        m_array=b_array=[]
        for i in range(epochs):
                if(i % 100 == 0 ):
                        print("Running {}/{}".format(i,epochs))
                (m,b) = step_gradient_descent_reg(data,m,b,lr)
                m_array.append(m)
                b_array.append(b)
        #np.array(m_array),np.array(b_array)

        plot(data,m,b)

        return (m,b,m_array,b_array)
```

And as a result i got the correct result that i have wanted . **line-of-best-fit** with optimal $w_\theta$ and $b_\theta$ finally thanks to *L2 Normalization* technique.

[image]

Comment: *L2 is Ridge Regularization technique* - is used for Penalty, it works by shrinking estimates towards zero - "This increases the bias of the model, making the fit worse on the training data, but also decreases the variance". *Normalization* makes different sence - it is scaling to make matrix well conditioned for faster convergence of [gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/315048/347139)