# How should I improve my Vectorized Gradient descent linear regression model?

Tags: linear-regression, gradient-descent, numpy, seaborn, python-3.x

I wrote a vectorized Gradient descent implementation of the linear regression model. The Dataset looks something like:[image]

It's Not Working properly as I am getting negative R Squared error I don't understand why ?? Should I decrease Alpha or No. of Iterations or is there any problem in my implementation what should I do?

My Regression plot looks something like below I don't know why I am getting such a line.
[image]

My Cost Function Error plot with respect to the number of iterations in Gradient descent looks something like below
[image]

R Squared Error is: -3.744682246118262

My Code Snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def CostFunction(Theta,DataMatrix):
    Size = DataMatrix.shape[0]
    Error = 0
    for i in range(0,Size):
        Feature = np.vstack(([1],np.array(DataMatrix[i][:-1]).reshape(-1,1)))
        Error += (np.transpose(Theta).dot(Feature) - DataMatrix[i][-1]) ** 2
    return (1/(2*Size))*Error

def GradientDescent(Theta,Alpha,DataMatrix,Iterations):
    Progress = []
    Iterate = 0
    Size = DataMatrix.shape[0]
    Error = np.zeros((DataMatrix.shape[1],1))
    while(Iterations):
        for i in range(0,Size):
            Feature = np.vstack(([1],np.array(DataMatrix[i][:-1]).reshape(-1,1)))        #Last Entry is Label Thats Why
            Error += (np.transpose(Theta).dot(Feature) - DataMatrix[i][-1])*Feature
        Theta -= Alpha*(1/Size)*Error
        if(Iterations % 10 == 0):
            Progress.append([Iterate,CostFunction(Theta,DataMatrix)])
            Iterate += 10
        Iterations -= 1
    return [Theta,Progress]

def ProgressCurve(Progress):
    Progress = [[i[0],i[1].ravel()[0]] for i in Progress]
    sns.lineplot(x = np.array(Progress)[:,0],y =  np.array(Progress)[:,1],marker = '*')
    plt.show()

def Prediction(Theta,Test):
    Predicted = []
    for i in range(0,Test.size):
        Feature = np.vstack(([1],np.array(Test[i]).reshape(-1,1)))
        Predicted.append(np.transpose(Theta).dot(Feature))
    return Predicted

def Error_Metric(Actual,Predicted):
    Actual = np.array(Actual,dtype = 'float64').reshape(-1,1)
    Predicted = np.array(Predicted,dtype = 'float64').reshape(-1,1)
    Error = (Actual - Predicted) ** 2
    Variance = (Actual - np.mean(Actual)*np.ones((Actual.shape[0],1))) ** 2
    return (1 - np.sum(Error)/np.sum(Variance))

def RegressionLine(X,Y,Orig_X,Orig_Y):
    Y = [i[0].ravel()[0] for i in Y]
    sns.scatterplot(x = Orig_X,y = Orig_Y,color = "blue")
    sns.lineplot(x = X,y = Y,color = "red")
    plt.show()

X = 2*np.random.rand(1000)
Y = 4 + 3*X + np.random.randn(1000)
X_Train,X_Test,Y_Train,Y_Test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size = 0.3,random_state = 0)
DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
DataFrame['X'] = X_Train
DataFrame['Y'] = Y_Train
DataMatrix = DataFrame.as_matrix()
ThetaParams = np.random.randn(2,1)
Theta,Progress = GradientDescent(ThetaParams,0.001,DataMatrix,50)
Prediction_Out = Prediction(Theta,np.array(X_Test))
Error = Error_Metric(Y_Test,Prediction_Out)
ProgressCurve(Progress)
RegressionLine(X_Test,Prediction_Out,X,Y)
print(Error)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like **number of iterations is very small compare to learning rate**. (50 vs 0.001). The optimizer can't converge when we look at the fitted line plot.

Try to increase number of iterations, it will help you. You can check this beautiful [work](https://towardsdatascience.com/gradient-descent-in-python-a0d07285742f) and my another [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56285/lowering-learning-rate-makes-my-accuracy-on-the-validation-set-go-down) about the problem.